# asp-append-version affecting html elements inside _Layout.cshtml

Tags: html, razor, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to add a language selector with flag in .net core mvc application. The picker selector is working fine but asp version is appended to the options of the dropdown.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./WebApplication2.styles.css"  />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
            <option data-content="<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-cz'></span>"></option>
            <option data-content="<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-de'></span>"></option>
            <option data-content="<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-gb'></span>"></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/site.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });
    </script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

[language picker with appended asp version in options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8xZV.png)

If I move the picker in any other file apart from `_Layout.cshtml` it works fine as expected. Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `@Html.Raw` to prevent the `Razor engine` from rendering these contents. So as to meet our needs.

**Using below code**

```
    <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
        <option data-content="@Html.Raw("<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-cz'></span>")"></option>
        <option data-content="@Html.Raw("<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-de'></span>")"></option>
        <option data-content="@Html.Raw("<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-gb'></span>")"></option>
    </select>
```

**Test Result**

[image]